# When are new contracts available?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I have a Gun Mettle campaign coin and have currently done 3 contracts. Two right when it came out then a third yesterday. I think I read something stating two contracts will be available per week, but when (i.e. what day(s) of the week) do they refresh?

Answer (score 2):

> You'll be assigned two skill-based contracts each week for the length
>   of the Gun Mettle Campaign.

This was copied  from the official website of Team Fortress.
So yes, 2 new contracts every week, there is no specific day one will be released.

http://www.teamfortress.com/gunmettle/

Comment: Define "each week"

Comment: Every week, from a specific day, When the day is NOT specificed, but as the drop system works, It can be at Wednesday, as seems like Valve refreshes most items (CSGO operation, loot, and etc)

Comment: The drop system resets every Thursday at 00:00UTC (which is 8pm EDT / 5pm PDT Wednesday).  Which happened to be a few hours after the update last week, so Valve likely just reset it early.

Comment: The third contract was an anomaly. There are only supposed to be 2 contracts per week, but Valve messed up and forgot to put cases on the contract drop list, so they were always awarding weapons.  They fixed it and added a third contract for everyone, presumably to get some cases in circulation... because you have to pay another $2.49 to unlock them.

Answer (score -3):

My guess would be that since the update got released on July the 2nd and it was a Thursday, the next contract will be the following Thursday, too.